# Error in building graphiql

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Node noob trying to get graphiql project running.
According to the instructions on this page:

https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/tree/master/example

Ran `npm run build` but I got some errors:

```
noob:/Users/noob/proj/js/graphiql$ npm run build

> graphiql@0.4.5 build /Users/noob/proj/js/graphiql
> . ./resources/build.sh

ReferenceError: [BABEL] src/codemirror/lint/json-lint.js: Unknown option: /Users/noob/proj/js/graphiql/package.json.optional
    at Logger.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:262:18)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:221:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:370:30)
    at OptionManager.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:412:12)
    at File.initOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
    at new File (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
    at transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:53:22)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/babel/util.js:62:12)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! graphiql@0.4.5 build: `. ./resources/build.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the graphiql@0.4.5 build script '. ./resources/build.sh'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the graphiql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     . ./resources/build.sh
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls graphiql
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/noob/proj/js/graphiql/npm-debug.lognoob
```

This is the log file:

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
    2 info using npm@2.14.4
    3 info using node@v0.12.7
    4 verbose node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
    5 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
    6 info prebuild graphiql@0.4.5
    7 info build graphiql@0.4.5
    8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    9 info graphiql@0.4.5 Failed to exec build script
    10 verbose stack Error: graphiql@0.4.5 build: `. ./resources/build.sh`
    10 verbose stack Exit status 1
    10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:214:16)
    10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
    10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
    10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
    11 verbose pkgid graphiql@0.4.5
    12 verbose cwd /Users/noob/proj/js/graphiql
    13 error Darwin 14.5.0
    14 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
    15 error node v0.12.7
    16 error npm  v2.14.4
    17 error code ELIFECYCLE
    18 error graphiql@0.4.5 build: `. ./resources/build.sh`
    18 error Exit status 1
    19 error Failed at the graphiql@0.4.5 build script '. ./resources/build.sh'.
    19 error This is most likely a problem with the graphiql package,
    19 error not with npm itself.
    19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    19 error     . ./resources/build.sh
    19 error You can get their info via:
    19 error     npm owner ls graphiql
    19 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How does anyone debug this stuff? Where would I start?
Thanks in advance.

Update:

I get the same error if I run `babel` on the file `json-lint.js` in the directory `graphiql/src/codemirror/lint`:

`babel json-lint.js`

Answer (score 0):

The build is almost certainly running against a version of Babel that has removed the `optional` option. You can tell because the errors are coming from `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` – a sign that the build is running against a globally-installed version of Babel rather than the one specified by `graphiql`'s `package.json`.

My guess is that you haven't installed the project-local version of Babel yet, so the build script is falling back to the global one. Try running `npm install` before running `npm run build`.

Comment: Submitted a pull request to make sure this doesn't happen again. https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/pull/95